# Access denied when using aws cli but allowed in web console

Tags: aws-cli

My IAM account has "admin" privilege, at least supposedly. I can perform all operations as far as I can tell in web console. For example,
[image: aws gui]

Recently I downloaded aws-cli and [quickly configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration) it by supplying access keys, default region and output format. I then tried to issue some commands and found most of them, but not all, have permission issues. For example

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.243 Python/3.7.4 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.233
$ aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
$ aws ec2 describe-instances

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
$ aws iam get-user
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "xxx@xxx.xxx",
        "UserId": "xxxxx",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::nnnnnnnnnn:user/xxx@xxx.xxx",
        "CreateDate": "2019-08-21T17:09:25Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "2019-09-21T16:11:34Z"
    }
}
```

It appears to me that cli, which is authenticated using access key, has a different permission set from web console, which is authenticated using MFA.

Why is permission inconsistent between CLI and GUI? How to make it consistent?

Comment: Have you generated the private and public keys? Have you configure them on this machine where you are trying to use aws cli?

Comment: @muasif80, cli uses access key rather than RSA pri/pub keys. I have RSA keys but they are used to ssh to ec2, not for cli authn. I have also generated access key for cli.

Comment: run the cli command with --debug, you;ll see how it is authenticated and based on that you can see if you're using the correct role/user etc

Comment: @JamesDean, --debug only dumps local call stacks. The deny occurs at server-side so it doesn't help. All I got from server is 403 response code and some meaningless hash codes in response body with --debug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out following statement in one of my policies blocked CLI access due to lacking MFA.

```
{
      "Condition": {
        "BoolIfExists": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotAction": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "sts:GetSessionToken"
      ],
      "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA"
},
```

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. From policy i am not able to see why accessong from console is blocked. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I also faced this issue and i fixed by authenticating CLI with MFA. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/

Answer (score 6):

If you replace `BoolIfExists` with `Bool`, it should work. Your CLI requests would not be denied because of not using MFA.

Opposite of https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/

Comment: Thanks. You joggled my memory. I forgot MFA was set for CLI as well

Answer (score 4):

To remain really secure check this good explanation: [MFA token for AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/?nc1=h_ls)

In few steps

1. Get a temporary 36 hours session token.

```
aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:iam::123456789012:mfa/user --token-code code-from-token

{
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "secret-access-key",
        "SessionToken": "temporary-session-token",
        "Expiration": "expiration-date-time",
        "AccessKeyId": "access-key-id"
    }
}
```

2. Save these values in a mfa profile configuration.

```
    [mfa]
        aws_access_key_id = example-access-key-as-in-returned-output
        aws_secret_access_key = example-secret-access-key-as-in-returned-output
        aws_session_token = example-session-Token-as-in-returned-output
```

3. Call with the profile

```
aws --profile mfa
```

Ps: Don't do the cron job as suggested, it goes again the security.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and I fixed it by adding my user to a new group with administrator access in IAM.

to do this go to [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam), Users, click on your user and then [add permissions]
in the next screen click [Create group] and then pick administrator access

[image]

Comment: My account didn't have the group/policy before. After I added to it, I still get access denied error.

Comment: Are you sure that your user has the correct access type? when you create a user you can choose between "Programmatic access:
Enables an access key ID and secret access key for the AWS API, CLI, SDK, and other development tools. " and "AWS Management Console access
Enables a password that allows users to sign-in to the AWS Management Console. ".
maybe try creating a new user with console access.
I think this could be your problem because when I do aws iam get-user I get a different output than yours, mine doesn't have the field ' "PasswordLastUsed": "XXXX" '

Comment: Access key wasn't enabled at time of my account creation but rather added after the fact. The order of granting couldn't matter - just like you can add yourself to admin group later on.